# How can i start looping through json after all the data is received not to break swiper size?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swiper.js

I am using Swiper React to create a slide. I loop through the json data to create slider elements. I think because i asynchronously pull the data, it messes up the sliders size. I can only show one slide element eventhough i set slidesPerView to 5. When i resize the window on desktop or turn to landscape from portrait on mobile, it fixes. How can i fix this problem? Maybe starting Object.map after all the data received but i couldn't do that with axios or fetch. Here is my code.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Container, Box, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import Story from "./Story";
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import "swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css";
import SwiperCore, { Autoplay } from "swiper";
import axios from "axios";

SwiperCore.use([Autoplay]);

const Fragmanlar = () => {
  const [trailer, setTrailer] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const url = "URLHERE";
    const fetchItems = async () => {
      const result = await axios(url);

      const res = result.data;
      setTrailer(res);
    };

    fetchItems();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Container maxWidth='lg'>
        <Swiper
          spaceBetween={0}
          slidesPerView={5}
          wrapperTag='ul'
          autoplay={true}
        >
          {trailer.map((item) => (
            <SwiperSlide tag='li' key={item.id}>
              <Story poster={item.poster} />
            </SwiperSlide>
          ))}
        </Swiper>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Fragmanlar;
```

Comment: How about rendering the swiper only after you have items ? `{Boolean(trailer.length) && <Swiper ....>...</Swiper>}`

Comment: It worked! Thank you.